# PHP Login - Ending into redirect loop

Tags: php

I really don't know much in php so my friend helped me to make login page.
However I end up into redirect loop if login information is correct.

Here's my code:

> index.php - Page

```
<?php
     if (!$_SESSION['ajslkajslkgjals'])
     header('Location: login.php');
?>
```

> login.php - Page

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once('config.php');

$query   = "SELECT * FROM admins";
$result  =  mysql_query($query);
$num     =  mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();

$i = 0;

while ($i < $num) {
    $admin_user = mysql_result($result, $i, "admin_username");
    $admin_pass = mysql_result($result, $i, "admin_password");
    $i++;
}

if(isset($_POST['login-form'])) {
    $admin_username = $_POST['username'];
    $admin_password = $_POST['password'];


    if($admin_username==$admin_user && $admin_password==$admin_pass) {
        $_SESSION['ajslkajslkgjals'] = $admin_user;
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();

    } else {
        $status = "<script>
                    $.ajax({ 
                        url: '/',
                        data: {action: 'test'},
                        type: 'post',
                        success: function() {
                            notifyBox();
                        }
                    });
                   </script>";

    }
}

if(isset($_SESSION['ajslkajslkgjals'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
?>
```

I will appreciate if anyone could give me some tips of where I made mistake ?
I just don't get it! Thank you.

Comment: Don't call `mysql_close();` It isn't necessary, and will prevent you from fetching rows with `mysql_result()` when you need them, resulting in NULL values compared to your input strings later on.

Comment: Okay Michael. I have removed mysql_close();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of login.php you have a redirect to index.php. In index you don't start the session so that if always executes the redirect.

Comment: That is amazing and simple and quick!
Thank you for your help, so much :)

Comment: You also have a redirect about halfway through login.php. And you also shouldn't be asking for the entire table for your usernames then iterating through it. Let your database query sort that out for you.

Comment: If I solved your problem, please click the check next to my post.

Comment: I will... I always do. It's just that timer thing...
About that comment answer, I have no ideas what are you trying to tell me :)

Comment: "SELECT * FROM admins" this pulls all the data from the table `admins`. You should be pulling information from the table where your username = the username submitted from the form. And don't forget to sanitize the search or else you can be subject to sql injection. Also mysql_ functions for php are going to be depreciated, use mysqli or pdo_mysql

Comment: Oh... Well I am stuck but it is good for now. I will look up for an paid login script in that case. Thank you for tips!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20418/discussion-between-james-mcdonnell-and-nenad-dvl)